# Primefaces p:picklist - how I capture the event of selecting an item in the target list?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, picklist

I'd like to re-render a component when a item from the picklist target list is selected by the user.

How do I do that?

---

UPDATE (December 17th, 2013)

I've described the full solution for this problem here  - http://leonotepad.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/primefaces-capturing-target-list-item.html

Thanks @Hatem I could not solve this without your answer.

Basically, it was this:

I have a @ViewScoped managed bean with a p:pickList filtered by a p:selectMany component using a p:ajax update event.

Like this

```
<p:outputLabel for="siteFilter" value="Site Filter:" style="width:100px;"/>
<p:selectOneMenu converter="#{siteTypeConverter}" id="siteFilter" value="#{myMB.selectedSiteType}" style="width:200px;">              
   <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Site Type" itemValue="#{null}" />
   <f:selectItems value="#{myMB.siteTypeFilterList}" var="st" itemLabel="#{st.name}" itemValue="#{st}" />
   <p:ajax update="sites" listener="#{myMB.handleSiteTypeFilterChange}" oncomplete="rebindClicks()"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:outputLabel for="sites" value="Sites:" style="width:100px;"/>
<p:pickList
   widgetVar="xyzabc"
   id="sites"
   value="#{myMB.sites}"
   var="site"                 
   converter="#{siteConverter}"
   itemLabel="#{site.siteType.name}.#{site.name}"
   itemValue="#{site}" />
```

The idea here is to trigger a new event when the user clicks on some pickList target list item.

So, as suggested by @Hatem, we have to bind the click event to each one of the target elements. Like this

```
(...)
   <p:remoteCommand name="updateCommand" action="#{myMB.updateAccounts}" update="accounts"/>
</h:form>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="pickListHack.js" />   
(...)
```

Notice that I had to add it AFTER the form.

and pickListHack.js is located at WebContent/resources/js/pickListHack.js

```
function rebindClicks() {
    xyzabc.jq.on('click','.ui-picklist-target li',function(){
        var item = $(this).attr('data-item-value');
        alert(item);
        updateCommand([{name:'param', value:item}]);
   });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    rebindClicks();
});
```

The trick here seems to be that, after the update event, the binds are lost, so we have to rebind them after the update. That's  why p:ajax has that oncomplete event.

Finally, when the user clicks on the element from the target list, we call the updateCommand, declared via p:remoteCommand.

Notice that the selected item is passed as a parameter called "param". We get this parameter back in the managed bean like this

```
public void updateAccounts(){
   String value = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("param");
   System.out.println(">"+value);
   this.accounts = value;
}
```

In this case, the value is just the ID, because that's what my siteConverter does to the object.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class SiteConverter implements Converter,Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -194442504109002565L;

    @EJB
    private MyEJB myEJB;

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2)
            throws ConverterException {

        if (arg2 != null){
            Site s = myEJB.getSiteById(Long.parseLong(arg2));
            return s;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
            throws ConverterException {

        if (arg2 != null){
            Site s = (Site)arg2;
            return String.valueOf(s.getId());
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question could use a whole lot more detail. Do you mean when an item is highlighted in the target list? Or when a transfer occurs?

Comment: The picklist has two lists, source and target. The event I am looking for is when the user selects an item from the picklist target list. This is different from the transfer event. You may even assume that both lists come with pre-initialized items in both sides and the user chooses a specific target item before any transfer event (if any)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way should do it.

*remoteCommand*

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateCommand" update="componentId" />
```

*p:pickList*

```
<p:pickList id="pickList" widgetVar="pickListVar" value="#{pickListBean.cities}" 
 var="city" itemLabel="#{city}" itemValue="#{city}" />
```

*JS*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   PF('pickListVar').jq.on('click','.ui-picklist-target li',function(){
       updateCommand();//remoteCommand to update
       //and you can get the item value and lable
       $(this).attr('data-item-value');
       $(this).attr('data-item-lable');
   });
});
```

**EDIT:**

And if your pickList is updated regularly by another component, you would lose the click event after all.

In this case you might want to bind the click on the parent container component of the pickList.

For example:

```
 $('#formId').on('click','.ui-picklist-target li',function(){
       updateCommand();//remoteCommand to update
       //and you can get the item value and lable
       $(this).attr('data-item-value');
       $(this).attr('data-item-lable');
   });
```

But again if any other component has updated the whole form, you would lose the event binding..

Comment: I don't understand this. How are you linking the javascript function and the pickList?

Comment: I'm not linking anything, since the output of the pickList is a normal HTML !
I do a couple of [jQuery selects](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) based on the picklist css classes, and [hook an event](http://api.jquery.com/on/) of specific dom element (ex. li) and when this element is clicked, it means that it's selected. simply I call the remoteCommand when it's selected. @kolossus

Comment: @HatemAlimam, this answer makes perfect sense. Although, I don't know why my browser says pickListVar is undefined. (widgetVar not working?). If I try calling jq from the ID [for example $('#am\\:sites').jq.on(...)], I get "TypeError: $(...).jq is undefined". If I try alert($('#am\\:sites'));
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#am\\:sites').on('click','.ui-picklist-source li',function(){
       alert($(this).attr('data-item-value'));
   });
});, the object is not null, no error msg is raised but nothing happens :-(

Comment: That's quite strange ! If you copy the same exact code inside the document ready, and execute it in the demo primefaces webapp (in the console) you would perfectly get the expected results. One more thing, you have to make sure that you don't have js errors in the page. I mean the page has to be error free from any js errors. Please share your pickList code, and the js so far, that would help. @LeonardoKenji

Comment: @HatemAlimam I've added a sample project in my google drive - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B16ze8CjSphhZ3QwNTZON0NURTQ/edit?usp=sharing - I am using apache tomee 1.6.0

Comment: @HatemAlimam, moving the <h:outputScript library="js" name="pickListHack.js" /> to the end of h:form did the trick.

Comment: or you can add `target="head"` to the outputScript, it also should do the trick.. @LeonardoKenji

Comment: I finally got what was happening here. In the pet project I've shared, the pickList events are bound on document.ready. But the pickList I have in my real project is updated by another component, so, on update, I have to re-bind the click events, it seems. :-(

Comment: No,you don't have to rebind, if you bind the event on the parent container, for example of the form. I Will update the answer with an example.

Comment: well, I've added a method here to rebind and it worked :-) my pickList were updated by a p:selectOneMenu with p:ajax. Just added a call to the rebind js method in the oncomplete and it seems to work now.